# MoPub ConsentStatus after ConsentDialog is closed?

Tags: android, mopub

When the user clicks the Close icon of the `ConsentDialog`, `ConsentDialogActivity.finish()` is called:

```
mView = new ConsentDialogLayout(this);
mView.setConsentClickListener(new ConsentDialogLayout.ConsentListener() {
    @Override
    public void onConsentClick(ConsentStatus status) {
       saveConsentStatus(status);
       setCloseButtonVisibility(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseClick() {
       finish();
    }
});
```

What is the `ConsentStatus` in this case? (Does closing the `ConsentDialog` count as "consent given" or "consent denied"?

Answer (score 1):

> Does closing the ConsentDialog count as "consent given" or "consent denied"

Closing the consent dialog does nothing. The consent state remains "Unknown", and publishers will need to display the consent dialog again at a later time to obtain the user's consent.

You can listen to the [`ConsentStatusChangeListener`](https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/blob/master/mopub-sample/src/main/java/com/mopub/simpleadsdemo/MoPubSampleActivity.java#L133-L146) to get notified when a consent change happens. You will have access to the old consent state, the new consent state, and whether you can continue collecting personal info. In this case, you will notice that the listener is not called for consent dialog dismissals.

When in doubt, you can also always call `PersonalInfoManager.getPersonalInfoConsentStatus()` to get the current consent status.